# What does this regex mean?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following expression for regex. Can someone tell me what it does? I can't find any reference to [?:]

Thanks

```
"abcd (?<result>.*?)[?:]"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches any characters besides `?` or `:` until (and including) a `?` or `:` and places the text before the `?` or `:` into a group named `result`.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I could not understand the ?:. Now I realize there's it's looking for one or the other. Great help. I will make accepted.